# How to subscribe to slot with Rust?

Tags: solana-program, slots

The `PubsubClient::slot_subscribe(&args.endpoint).unwrap();` returns an error ``Err `value: ConnectionError(Url(UnsupportedUrlScheme))'` when using `"https://api.devnet.solana.com"`

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the WS url for pubsub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `wss://api.devnet.solana.com` as endpoint